# Lightweight distributed file system implemention in java

Tags: java

We are working on an JavaEE application where user can upload images,videos(usually a zip contains a lot of small files) to the server, generally we will save the file(files) to a certain local directory, and then user can access them.

But things get complicated once the application is deployed on multiple servers in front of which a load balance resides.  Say there are two servers `Server1` and `Server2`, and one user try to upload some files, and this request is dispatched to `Server2`, nothing wrong here. And later, another user try to access the file, and his request is dispatched to `Server1`, then the application can not find the file.

Sounds like I need a distributed file system, while I only need a few features:

```
1)Nodes can detect each other by themselves.
2)read and write file/directory
3)unzip archive
4)automatically distributes data based on the available space of nodes
```

HDFS is too big for my application,  and I does not need to process the data, I only care about the storage.

Is there a java based lightweight alternative solution which can be embedded in my application?

Comment: What is the reason for having multiple servers? Is it about load balancing or transparent failover?

Comment: Load balancing is the main point.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably solve this at the operating system level using shared [network attached storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). (If you don't have a dedicated NAS available, you can have an application server act as NAS by sharing the relevant directory with NFS).